# How to combine css selectors

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, selectors-api

I use webdriver and often work with css selector and wondering if the amount of code I write to traverse each level can be decreased. Following is the javascript code to access an element and similar code in java would be present in my code.

in the below example I used 3 css selectors to traverse 3 levels and can I combine them together or atleast simplify.

```
document.querySelector('.datagrid').querySelectorAll(".even")[3].querySelectorAll('tbody tr')
```

Comment: [CSS Selectors in Selenium](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/) Helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [descendant](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) or [child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) selectors (technically "combinators") to combine the first part:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.datagrid .even')[3].querySelectorAll('tbody tr')
```

...but it will make the browser work a bit harder than your code does, because the first part of your code (`document.querySelector('.datagrid')`) will stop looking when it finds the *first* matching element, and then look for `.even` elements only within that. The above looks for **all** `.even` elements that have `.datagrid` ancestors. So it may need to search more of the document. Most of the time that doesn't matter, but it's worth pointing out. The above also assumes that there are at least four `.even` elements in the first `.datagrid`. If there aren't, your code would throw an error (because of the attempt to call `.querySelectorAll` on `[3]`, which would be `null`), whereas the above code *might* throw an error (if there aren't four *in total* on the page), or might refer to an `.even` element in a subsequent `.datagrid` rather than the first.

The `[3]` makes it tricky to combine that with the one that follows. It's tempting to use `.even:nth-child(3)` or `.even:nth-of-type(3)`, but that would be a mistake, because neither of those counts matches for `.even` and then takes the third one. `nth-child` matches only elements that are *both* `.even` **and** the third child element of their parent (considering all elements, not just `.even` ones). `nth-of-type` does the same thing, but only considering other elements that have the same tag. If you have other non-`.even` elements with the same tag name, it will be wrong.

Sometimes you hear talk about adding a selector (similar to the `:eq` provided by jQuery) to do what you're talking about, but the problem (as I understand it) is it would require a fundamental change to how selector engines process selectors (which is right-to-left). (There's also the problem that jQuery is incredibly widely used, and uses `0` as the first element's index, whereas CSS uses `1` in similar situations. So CSS would have to use something other than `:eq` — perhaps `:index`? — to avoid confusion.)

Comment: I would +1 this for each paragraph if I could :)

Comment: Two things I question about your answer. First, as I understand it, `querySelector('.datagrid')` only gets the _first_ `.datagrid` element, whereas your combined `querySelectorAll('.datagrid .even')` would pull from _all_ `.datagrid` elements. Second, if there are _nested_ `.even` elements (so `.even` is parent to other `.even` elements), would the OP's version and your combined version return those elements _in the same order_ such that the `[3]` element was in fact the same for both sets of returned values?

Comment: @ScottS: Oddly, I don't seem to have got a notification of your comment. Excellent observations. It's absolutely true that the above will consider `.even` elements within more than just the first `.datagrid`, I've updated the answer to explain that. The order of the matched `.even` elements will be unchanged, though; both the OP's code and the above will give the `.even` elements in document order, nested or not. But the above also behaves differently if there are multiple `.datagrid` elements and the first doesn't have four `.even`  elements in it, so I've flagged that up again. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottS: In answer to your second question, the spec says it must always return elements in document order. What "document order" exactly refers to is defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#the-apis which also covers nested elements.

Comment: @BoltClock and T.J. Crowder: Thank you both for the clarifications on "document order," especially the spec link with its notation about "depth-first pre-order traversal."

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything you can do with a css selector you can do with `querySelector()`, so if you know your css selectors, you should be ok.

> "The string argument pass to querySelector must follow the CSS syntax" - extract from the API.